# Javascript, matching multiple instances of all text between two flags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have multiple flags in code that I need to find and deal with, my node JavaScript code is only returning one match.

```
/*~S*/holder.reset();/*S~*/
holder.play();
/*~S*/holder.addEventListener("click",reportClick);/*S~*/
holder.pause();
    
let reg = /\/\*~S\*\/([\s\S]*)\/\*S~\*\//gm
optionalTrack = data.match(reg)
```

I want optionalTrack to return two items (everything between EACH flag):

1. /*~S*/holder.reset();/*S~*/
2. /*~S*/holder.addEventListener("click",reportClick);/*S~*/

but I'm getting one item (everything between the first and last flag):

```
/*~S*/holder.reset();/*S~*/
holder.play();
/*~S*/holder.addEventListener("click",reportClick);/*S~*/
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `[\s\S]*` => `[\s\S]*?`

Comment: ah! That was easy, thank you